# Will the function in assertRaises complete before unit test ends?

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
def test_invalid_host(self):
    controller = SSHController("host name")
    self.assertRaises(SSHException, controller.login())
#test_invalid_host End
```

Will controller.login() finish before the test passes or will the test pass as soon as SSHException is raised?

Comment: I think you need to pass controller.login without calling it (i.e. remove `()`). And it will stop when it raises the error.

Comment: `assertRaises` asserts that calling `controller.login` raises an `SSHException`. If the function doesn't raise one -- even if it does internally but then catches it again -- then `assertRaises` will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as the SSHException is raised, the exception is caught by the `assertRaises` method. So the rest of `controller.login` is not run.

PS. Be sure to call

```
self.assertRaises(SSHException, controller.login)
```

**without** the parentheses after `controller.login`. If you write `controller.login()` then indeed the `login` method would be called before the `assertRaises` method is called since all arguments are evaluated before being passed to a function/method.

Comment: I removed the (), but the test isn't passing after the exception is raised. Instead the function controller.login is handling the exception.

Comment: @Takkun: The controller.login method must not catch (or must re-raise) the exception if you wish `assertRaises` to see the exception.